# SVN: Merge from branch to trunk where both contains new content

Tags: svn, version-control, merge

This is my first time with subversion and I have a problem that I can't figure out. Coulnd't find the right answer neither.

I copied remote trunk (master) into my computer and made changes on it. While I was working my copy someone else updated remote trunk with new features. Now I have codes that trunk has not, and trunk has codes my branch has not. When I try to pull latest updates from master trunk my local changes disappears and I cant merge my local changes into trunk because I don't have the latest updates from trunk. I use TortoiseSVN. Can someone help me on this issue?

Answer (score -1):

The correct answer would be "read the documentation before asking".

First of all, you have sync your branch with trunk (fetch changes from trunk) and resolve any conflicts if there are any. Merge your branch to trunk afterwards.

Read the documentation:

- [SVNBook | Keeping a Branch in Sync](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.stayinsync)
- [SVNBook | Reintegrating a Branch](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.reintegrate)
- [TortoiseSVN Manual | Merging](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-merge.html)